# Why does Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) return 0?

Tags: java, calendar

why does the following return 0?

```
int currMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Comment: what is the type of `c`?

Comment: @Mark E: [Calendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The Months are numbered from 0 (January) to 11 (December).

**Reference:**

- [`Calendar.MONTH`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

Comment: The last depends on the number of months in the year....

Comment: @Byers: And whether "0" means "January" or "Abib" or "Zhengyue" depends on what calendar you are using. But I think it's a fair assumption that he's talking about the Gregorian calendar. Which last I checked has had 12 months in a year since it was invented in 1582. I'm all for keeping systems flexible, but on the list of things likely to change, the number of months in a calendar year is pretty far down.

Comment: FWIW, Java supports Undecimber, a thirteenth month of the year used in lunar calendars...

Comment: @Brian where can I find that?

Comment: @Sean http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: @Brian arghh, I was blind. sorry.

Answer (score 12):

Not natural indexing, but unnatural thinking of Sun people. :-)

Comment: I'm wondering: should I upvote this or flag as offensive? I'll go for neither

Comment: No, I don't think so.  Why should January be represented **numerically** as 1 (I'm not talking about textually)?  Sure the String representation can be 1 in many the way many cultures write out dates, but that's handled by date formatters, not Calendar. 1+ rep for the smiley though.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find mapping 1 (numeric) to 1 (text) just a wee bit easier... :-)

Comment: I think that its definitely right to start it from 0 to conform with other indexing methods in Java. It was a dumb question on my behalf really - sorry to waste expert time!

Comment: @David, it is not a dumb question, as the semantics are very confusing. I do however disagree with you. 0 really is the source of a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

oops! sorry - I figured it out. Natural Indexing of course!!!

Comment: You don't use numbers for months but should use the Calendar constants such as Calendar.JANUARY (which as you're finding out is 0).  The API shows this.

Comment: Calendar constants don't make any sense if you're trying to get the month number.  In that case one must just remember to increment the return value.  I find it quite annoying, especially since days are returned starting with 1...

Comment: yeah that is a bit stranfe...